# mail to gmail does not work with "SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"

Tags: pi-zero, ssmtp

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 model B+ 
that sends mail to gmail perfectly
and in /var/log/syslog I see

```
SSL connection using RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
```

My new PiZero can NOT send mail to gmail,
and in /var/log/syslog I see

```
SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

How can I change that setting ?
Thanks.

PD.- 
working one has :

```
pi@odin:~ $ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u7, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
```

The non-working is :

```
sebas@pi0alby:~ $ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
```

Comment: Why do you present us the version of **ssh**? What has ssh to do with sending emails, or the *Secure Socket Layer* **SSL** giving you a message? That isn't an error message. What operating system do you use? How do you send emails?

Comment: The op sys is a Raspbian : uname -a = 
Linux pi0alby 4.19.57+ #1244 Thu Jul 4 18:42:50 BST 2019 armv6l GNU/Linux

pi@pi0alby:~ $ cat /etc/debian_version
10.0

Comment: i send email with 
  $ echo “hello my body” | mail –s “my subject” myemail@gmail.com